# Justificar texto en report viewer RDLC

Tags: rdlc, reportviewerreporte

**e estado intentando justificar el texto dentro mi report viewer y no lo e logrado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sabes que puedes modificar el texto a gusto como si fuera un documento de excel? Pulsa sobre el objeto que quieras y en la parte superior derecha de VS estarán las opciones de edición.

Answer (score 0):

Solo le pasas la cadena de texto, y la cantidad de letras aproximadas. 
no olvides agregar el using System.Text.

```
 public static List<string> JustificarTexto(string text, int width)
    {
        string[] palabras = text.Split(' ');
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        int length = palabras.Length;
        List<string> resultado = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            sb1.AppendFormat("{0} ", palabras[i]);
            if (sb1.ToString().Length > width)
            {
                resultado.Add(sb2.ToString());
                sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                sb2 = new StringBuilder();
                i--;
            }
            else
            {
                sb2.AppendFormat("{0} ", palabras[i]);
            }
        }
        resultado.Add(sb2.ToString());

        List<string> resultado2 = new List<string>();
        string temp;

        int index1, index2, salto;
        string target;
        int limite = resultado.Count;
        foreach (var item in resultado)
        {
            target = " ";
            temp = item.ToString().Trim();
            index1 = 0; index2 = 0; salto = 2;

            if (limite <= 1)
            {
                resultado2.Add(temp);
                break;
            }
            while (temp.Length <= width)
            {
                if (temp.IndexOf(target, index2) < 0)
                {
                    index1 = 0; index2 = 0;
                    target = target + " ";
                    salto++;
                }
                index1 = temp.IndexOf(target, index2);
                temp = temp.Insert(temp.IndexOf(target, index2), " ");
                index2 = index1 + salto;

            }
            limite--;
            resultado2.Add(temp);
        }
        return resultado2;
    }
```

Comment: Hola Wilder, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Recuerda que no todas las preguntas deben responderse. El autor ha de añaidr más explicacion de lo que le pasa, y lo que ha intentado o investigado para resolverlo. No se suelen responder preguntas asi para no dar *en bandeja* una solucion que posiblemente no se hayan molestado ellos mismos en buscar. Además, mira [answer] para mejorar la calidad de tus respuestas ya que solo codigo no es considerado de buena calidad al no llevar consigo la explicacion oportuna. Un saludo.

Comment: el documento que tengo es estatico en la mayoria, el cual ya esta directo en la RDLC y algunos parametros que me llegan desde la DB